# Issue with SecureRandom: PRNG not consistent in java 1.5

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I am facing an issue with SecureRandom in java.

This was the code that used to work as expected ,Generating PRNG when it ran on java 1.4.
So basically when it was executed any weblogic server running on 1.4 generated same PRNG

**Problem:**
   In a clustered env , data is encrypted  in the one weblogic 10 instance , and the same  needs to decrypted in another weblogic 10 instance.Apparently not working

**FYI:**
We didnt face this issue in Weblogic 8.1 as it was runing in 1.4 and the key generated in both servers returned same as the secureRandom was generated with the same SEED.

**Code:**

```
SecureRandom srandom1 = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        srandom1.setSeed(TestClient.RANDOM_SEED);

            KeyGenerator keyGen1 = null;
            try {
                keyGen1 = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {

            }

            keyGen1.init(srandom1);
            Key g_Key_with = keyGen1.generateKey();
```

but we observe that after migrating to java 1.5 , the above functionality breaks.
The issue here is SecureRandom seems to generate different PRNG for the same seed in two different weblogic 10 Servers running on Java 1.5 ?

I did refer the thread : http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5298375

so could anyone please suggest the alternative to using SecureRandom /possible fix ?

**UPDATE**

[b]Update:[/b]

Possible solution :
We could store the key in a keystore  and place it in a File Location. and use the same key for decrypting.
But how would i go about doing it in a clustered environment. As key generated in one weblogic instance , needs to decrypted in the another.

Could you let me know the approach for this as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was answered at forums.sun.com. It isn't meant to provide the same sequence from the same seed. It's secure. Thats what secure means in this context.Your expectations are misplaced. This is all documented.

Comment: yes i am not refutting it , but FYI the very same code worked in JAVA 1.4.
My requirement is to encrypt and decrypt data , for which i would need the same key. I would update the question to include more info.
Please provide if you have any solution ?

Comment: There cannot possibly be a solution given that your requirement violates the specification of the API you are using. There are many standard ways to generate session keys - use one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if the default provider is changed from 1.4 to 1.5
There is similar case on Android : [Encryption error on Android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383006/encryption-error-on-android-4-2)