# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am developing an android application in which it is necessary to decrypt the file. I specify an algorithm as follows:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "Crypto");
```

But get the error:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding

What is my mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try and use

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

If you don't specify the provider, it will look for the highest prioritized provider that does implement it.

Comment: I can not use this method in android 4.2 and above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383006/encryption-error-on-android-4-2

Comment: @MarkKorzhov You cannot use the `getRawKey()` from that question, because it uses `SecureRandom` but if you use that you don't understand cryptography anyway. Although the same could be said about ECB mode, mind you.

Comment: @MarkKorzhov: What happens if you do it anyway?

Answer (score -3):

Define the exception handler. You need to add the proper *import* in the begging of your class, like this:

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
```

Look [here how](http://shra.ru/2014/11/nosuchalgorithmexception-oshibka)